# Symfony 2 AbstractToken Notice error in line 149

Tags: php, oop, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm develop the auth in Symfony2 and my user entity are joined with user category entity. When i'm trying to login, Symfony throws an error:

Notice: serialize(): "intusercategoryid"returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php line 149

**User entity:**

```
/**
 * Class User
 * @package UsersBundle\Entity
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer $intuserid
     */
    private $intuserid;

    /**
     * @var string $varpassword
     */
    private $varpassword;

    /**
     * @var string $varsalt
     */
    private $varsalt;

    /**
     * @var mixed $category
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @return integer $intUserID.
     */
    public function getIntUserID()
    {
        return $this->intuserid;
    }

    // ......... //

    /**
     * @return UserCategory $category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $value
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCategory($value = null)
    {
        $this->category = $value;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Конструктор класса User
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userRoles = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->category = new UserCategory();
        $this->timeregister = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

**User category entity:**

```
/**
 * UserCategory
 */
class UserCategory
{
    /**
     * @var integer $intusercategoryid
     */
    private $intusercategoryid;

       // ...... //

    /**
     * Get intusercategoryid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIntUserCategoryId()
    {
        return $this->intusercategoryid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem description

After a few days I found the problem. The problem in my **entity variables access** (in question is **private**).

I read the php [documentation about serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and found that:

> Object's private members have the class name prepended to the member name; protected members have a '*' prepended to the member name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.

### Important

In [symfony 2 official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html), entity fields generates with **private access**

Example from documentation:

```
// src/Acme/BlogBundle/Entity/BlogComment.php
namespace Acme\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\BlogComment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog_comment")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BlogComment
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $author
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var text $content
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var datetime $createdAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var BlogPost
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BlogPost")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $post;
}
```

### Solution

For resolving the error, I changed **private** access to **protected** and it worked:

**User entity:**

```
/**
 * Class User
 * @package UsersBundle\Entity
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer $intuserid
     */
    protected $intuserid;

    /**
     * @var string $varpassword
     */
    protected $varpassword;

    /**
     * @var string $varsalt
     */
    protected $varsalt;

    /**
     * @var mixed $category
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @return integer $intUserID.
     */
    public function getIntUserID()
    {
        return $this->intuserid;
    }

    // ......... //

    /**
     * @return UserCategory $category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $value
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCategory($value = null)
    {
        $this->category = $value;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Конструктор класса User
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userRoles = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->category = new UserCategory();
        $this->timeregister = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

**User category entity:**

```
/**
 * UserCategory
 */
class UserCategory
{
    /**
     * @var integer $intusercategoryid
     */
    protected $intusercategoryid;

       // ...... //

    /**
     * Get intusercategoryid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIntUserCategoryId()
    {
        return $this->intusercategoryid;
    }
}
```